# replace hyphen with %20 in GET

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, httprequest

I have rewritten the url so that every instance of `%20(space)` is replaced with a hyphen(-). Now the `%20` did not affect the retrieval of url as for instance it read `html%20and%20css` as `html and css`, but with the hyphen replace it views `html and css` as `html-and-css` and hence i do not retrieve things properly.

My problem is I would like to replace the hyphen with the space code when using the GET method:

```
          $search_query2 = $_GET['crs_category'];
```

Hence, I have to filter `$_GET['crs_category'];`to replace `"-"` with a space

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what exactly you're trying to do, but if you were able to replace the `%20` with a hyphen, why don't you just reverse the process for your `$_GET` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep reading your question over and over and the only logical conclusion I come out to, is that you have already replaced the original `%20` with hyphen. Now, you just want to reverse the process...?

If so, a simple `str_replace` will do the trick.

```
$string = 'html-and-css';
$string = str_replace('-', ' ', $string);

echo $string;
```

**Output:** html%20and%20css

Just replace my original `$string` with your `$_GET` `array`.

`$string = $_GET['crs_category'];`

Comment: thanks. Yeah i have to reverse the process because %20 was replace with - for clean url but i cant retrieve it as raw because html-and-css is different from html and css. technically wouldn't be better to do $string = str_replace('-', ' ', $string); that is %20 with an actual space because the output has to be html and css

Comment: @user3907211 Yes, if it has to be a space, that would be fine. I was just under the impression you were wanting `%20` back in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace()`

```
$search_query2 = str_replace("%20", "-", $_GET['crs_category']);
```

My test:

```
$crs_category = 'html%20and%20css';
$search_query2 = str_replace("%20", "-", $crs_category);
echo $search_query2;
```

Yields:

```
html-and-css
```